# Xcode 5.1.1 crashes when I build and run app

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-mavericks

I am using MacOSX 10.9.4 Maverick, Xcode 5.1.1 . When I try to launch an app in the simulator, I get a black screen, and then Xcode closes. I have read every post here but the result is the same. I have reinstalled Xcode 4 times.

```
Process:         Xcode [1408]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.1.1 (5085)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-5085000000000000~10
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 520942841
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [742]
Responsible:     Xcode [1408]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-08-11 20:13:21.024 +0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  F561F489-E878-36A0-F528-B5968C6B4C5E


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Sending performRunAction: to <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f9ca5c0e380> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f9ca5c0e380>
ProductBuildVersion: 5B1008
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Error getting value for key 'workerClass' of extension 'Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB'
UserInfo: {
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\" UserInfo=0x7f9caa062760 {DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in \U201ccom.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB\U201d at path \U201c/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin\U201d could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9caa1947d0 \"The bundle \U201cDebuggerLLDB\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.\"}";
}
Hints: 
  0: Sending performRunAction: to <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f9ca5c0e380> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f9ca5c0e380>
  1: Sending performAction: to <DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell: 0x7f9ca5c0e990> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f9ca5c0e380>
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff854bc244 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x0000000100d8fb10 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff8b408e75 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x0000000100c2cd67 -[DVTExtension valueForKey:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x00000001064dc10b -[DBGLLDBDebugLocalService operationWorkerWithLaunchSession:error:] (in DebuggerLLDBService)
  5  0x000000010aeaa3a0 (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
  6  0x0000000101713966 -[IDERunDestination runWorkerForLaunchSession:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x0000000101713694 -[IDERunDestination runOperationForLaunchSession:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  8  0x00000001019193c3 -[IDELaunchSchemeAction runOperationForExecutionEnvironment:withBuildOperation:buildParameters:buildableProductDirectories:schemeActionRecord:outError:actionCallbackBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
  9  0x0000000101879691 -[IDEScheme _executionOperationForExecutionEnvironment:build:onlyBuild:buildPurpose:buildCommand:schemeCommand:title:overridingProperties:destination:buildLog:filePath:overridingBuildConfiguration:restorePersistedBuildResults:invocationRecord:overridingTestingSpecifiers:error:actionCallbackBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
 10  0x0000000101876c6e -[IDEScheme runWithExecutionContext:buildIfNeeded:onlyBuild:destination:overridingProperties:commandName:invocationRecord:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 11  0x0000000101f1019a -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _actuallyPerformSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 12  0x0000000101f13acd __175-[IDEWorkspaceTabController _performSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 13  0x0000000101f138f2 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _performSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 14  0x0000000101f145ee __185-[IDEWorkspaceTabController _performDebuggableSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 15  0x0000000101f14b5b -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _forceSwitchToLLDBIfNecessary:preAlertHandler:completionHandler:] (in IDEKit)
 16  0x00000001038ccfae -[DVTDeveloperModeAlertHelper askToEnableDeveloperModeIfNecessaryWithCompletionHandler:] (in DVTDeveloperModeHelper)
 17  0x0000000101f1449d -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _performDebuggableSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 18  0x0000000101f150ed -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _runScheme:runDestination:invocationRecord:] (in IDEKit)
 19  0x0000000101e47420 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController runActiveRunContext:] (in IDEKit)
 20  0x0000000101f96c69 -[IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton performRunAction:] (in IDEKit)
 21  0x00007fff8eb16260 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 22  0x00000001012f5f85 __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 23  0x0000000100d8f842 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 24  0x00000001011c3b0e -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 25  0x0000000101346e09 -[DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell performAction:] (in DVTKit)
 26  0x00007fff8eb16260 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 27  0x00000001012f5f85 __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 28  0x0000000100d8f842 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 29  0x00000001011c3b0e -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 30  0x000000010128eb0f -[DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in DVTKit)
 31  0x00007fff8eb7b13d -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 32  0x00000001012aa9ef -[DVTMainStatusAwareButton mouseDown:] (in DVTKit)
 33  0x00000001012aa980 -[DVTRolloverTrackingButton mouseDown:] (in DVTKit)
 34  0x00007fff8eafca58 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 35  0x00007fff8ea9b5d4 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 36  0x0000000101d40600 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 37  0x00007fff8e8eb9f9 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 38  0x00007fff8e8d6783 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 39  0x00007fff922bb5fd start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInternalInconsistencyException
```

Comment: Does the file at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB exist?

Comment: Looks like a corrupted install.  I would try removing and reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the very first line of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and stepping through until you find the line that crashes?

Comment: This happens to me also. I had hoped this would have repaired itself when I upgraded to 6.1 but with no luck.  Most of the time xCode crashes when I try to run ANY application.  If I build first most of the time it will let me run it afterwards.  Have you found a fix?